# understanding python module "simpy" import statement semantics, and versioning

Tags: python, python-2.7, simulation

I am trying to build python simulation of M/M/c Queue and its variations. I search on the internet and it seems the simpy [Latest version 3](https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is pretty new. 
But at the main time, most of the established simulations are built with version 2.X

With the beginning,

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
```

instead of

```
import simpy
```

This makes really confusing.

What is the general difference and its evolution then? Anyone has experience with both of these versions. Thanks! One source could be [HERE](https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topical_guides/porting_from_simpy2.html)

Comment: If you're coding it yourself, what's holding you back from using version 3? Or do you need to use an existing simulation?

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your question that you think that the import statements are dealing with version information.  They are not.

`import simpy`

causes all the symbols ('names of things') to be imported into your 'namespace' (IE you can call them) under the namespace 'simpy'.

This means that if simpy has a function called `'run_stuff'`, then you can say

`result=simpy.run_stuff()`

in your code.

You can't say just

`result=run_stuff()`

In contrast, `from MODULE import *` imports all the symbols from the MODULE direct into your namespace, not under the MODULE namespace

This means if you say

`from simpy import *`

then you **can** say

`result=run_stuff()`

in your code.

Nothing to do with versions.